# JTree click event not working

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, listener, jtree

Hi I am new to the Jtree component.

I am adding nodes dynamically according to button click events. The nodes are added successfully when I click a button, but after adding a panel on node click event, the node functionality (ie, when clicking on node buttons that are visible) stops not working.

[image]

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event) {
    (tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString().startsWith("Channel")) {
            //if i click Channel node the device button is not visible
            //block button have to invisible
            //treePanel contains jtree
            treePanel.revalidate();
            treePanel.repaint();
            modbusButton.setEnabled(false);
            channelButton.setEnabled(false);
            blockButton.setEnabled(false);
            deviceButton.setEnabled(true);

            modbus2 mcon = null;
            try {
                mcon = new modbus2();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ModBusTree.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
            }



            ModbusMainPanel.rightPanel.removeAll();
            ModbusMainPanel.rightPanel.add(mcon.p2);
            ModbusMainPanel.rightPanel.revalidate();
            ModbusMainPanel.rightPanel.repaint();
        }
}
```

Comment: You will get better and quicker answers if you show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: You get errors or it's just the panel that remains blank? Can you give us the code that create `modbus2.p2`? Also I'd like to know if `rightPanel` is a static field of class `ModbusMainPanel` or `ModbusMainPanel` is a field that start with an uppercase?

Comment: Thanks for your code but it is too incomplete to make any useful observations. Consider posting a complete/compilable code that reproduces your problem, ..., an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get some insight from the tutorial section [*How to Use Trees: Dynamically Changing a Tree*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic), which cites [`DynamicTreeDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg), a compete example similar to what you're doing.

[image: DynamicTreeDemo]